# What is the correct way to modify dll.config of published project?

Tags: c#, app-config

I published a .net core console application to my test server and scheduled it to run using task scheduler.  I then wanted to turn on additional functionality using a switch from the app.config (that apparently turns into project.dll.config).  The modifications did not take effect however.  What is the correct way to modify my app.config file in this scenario?  Do I need to republish?  Maybe reschedule?

Answer (score 1):

The Console Application will need to be restarted to pick up any change in its `.config` files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is scheduled under task scheduler on a Windows server 2012 R2 box.  The next scheduled run did not pick up the change.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you won't need to republish or recompile, unless you modify a ".cs" file. Just need to restart the app, like @Hayden said.